# Ant XSLT task with fileset running out of memory/not freeing up memory

Tags: xslt, ant, out-of-memory, saxon

I have a big (1.9 GB) XML file which has data I want to insert into a MySQL database every month. I have made an Ant script for this.

The Ant XSLT task can't handle one file this big, so I have a task that uses xml_split (from xml-twig-tools) to split the 1.9 GB xml file into smaller xml files of roughly 4 MB.

This all goes well.

I use the following Ant xml to run the XSLT task over all these XML files:

```
    <target name="xsltransform" depends="split" description="Transform XML to SQL...">
            <xslt basedir="${import.dir}/" 
                  destdir="${import.dir}/sql/"
                  style="${xsl.filename}" force="true">
                    <mapper type="glob" from="*.xml" to="*.sql" />
                    <factory name="net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl"/>
            </xslt>
    </target>
```

The problem is, as soon as it starts on the first XML file, I see the 'RES' memory in linux *top* growing with every next XML file. As it is processing multiple (unrelated) xml files, I would suspect it would free up memory in between the translation of each xml file. Well, it doesn't... after two-hundred 4MB xml files, java throws an out-of-memory exception:

```
BUILD FAILED
/var/lib/hudson/jobs/EPDB_Rebuild_Monthly/workspace/trunk/buildfiles/buildMonthly.xml:67: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
at net.sf.saxon.tinytree.TinyTree.ensureNodeCapacity(Unknown Source)
at net.sf.saxon.tinytree.TinyTree.addNode(Unknown Source)
at net.sf.saxon.tinytree.TinyBuilder.startElement(Unknown Source)
at net.sf.saxon.event.Stripper.startElement(Unknown Source)
at net.sf.saxon.event.ReceivingContentHandler.startElement(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at net.sf.saxon.event.Sender.sendSAXSource(Unknown Source)
at net.sf.saxon.event.Sender.send(Unknown Source)
at net.sf.saxon.event.Sender.send(Unknown Source)
at net.sf.saxon.Controller.transform(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.TraXLiaison.transform(TraXLiaison.java:194)
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.XSLTProcess.process(XSLTProcess.java:812)
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.XSLTProcess.execute(XSLTProcess.java:408)
at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:390)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:411)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1360)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1329)
```

Is there something I can do to prevent the XSLT task eating up all my memory?
Or should I reconsider my approach?

Comment: As with all `OutOfMemoryError: heap space` problems, something is holding onto objects for too long. It could be Saxon (unlikely), or it could be your custom task. The way to diagnose is to pass `-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError` to the JVM, and see what objects are taking all the space. Use `ANT_OPTS` to pass this value.

Comment: can you iterate over ant invocations instead of having one ant task iterating over your files ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We are all going to agree that it should be letting go of the memory, but since it doesn't, you can try breaking up the `xslt` task in to seperate calls. e.g., using [Ant Contrib's `for` task](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/for.html)

```
<for param="file">
    <fileset dir="${import.dir}"/>
    <sequential>
        <xslt in="@{file}"
              destdir="${import.dir}/sql/"
              style="${xsl.filename}" force="true">
                <mapper type="glob" from="*.xml" to="*.sql" />
                <factory name="net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl"/>
        </xslt>
    </sequential>
</for>
```

If that doesn't do the trick, then since you are using Saxon, you can [calling Saxon's java classes directly](http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/using-xsl/commandline.xml) in a forked JVM. e.g.,

```
<java classname="net.sf.saxon.Transform" failonerror="true" fork="true">
                <arg value="-s:${import.dir}" />
                <arg value="-xsl:${xsl.filename}" />
                <arg value="-o:${import.dir}/sql" />
</java>
```

or you can try both

```
<for param="file">
    <fileset dir="${import.dir}"/>
    <sequential>
        <basename property="@{file}.base" file="@{file}" suffix="xml"/>
        <java classname="net.sf.saxon.Transform" failonerror="true" fork="true">
                <arg value="-s:@{file}" />
                <arg value="-xsl:${xsl.filename}" />
                <arg value="-o:${import.dir}/sql/${@{file}.base}.sql" />
        </java>
    </sequential>
</for>
```

and for bonus points you could try to speed things up a bit by doing it in parallel.

```
<for param="file">
    <fileset dir="${import.dir}"/>
    <parallel>
        <basename property="@{file}.base" file="@{file}" suffix="xml"/>
        <java classname="net.sf.saxon.Transform" failonerror="true" fork="true">
                <arg value="-s:@{file}" />
                <arg value="-xsl:${xsl.filename}" />
                <arg value="-o:${import.dir}/sql/${@{file}.base}.sql" />
        </java>
    </parallel>
</for>
```

Comment: All of this is golden. One thing forgotten on the samples, though, is a closing "/" tag for <fileset>.

Comment: I ended up using a solution quite similar to yours. Thanks!